# Changing the password of a system user from ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, windows-server

Our ColdFusion website uses local system accounts on the web server to authenticate users.  We have an old piece of code on our intranet that used a custom tag called `CFX_NT_USERDB` to remove users and recreate them with a new password.  This worked great for us as user accounts are not used for any other purpose that website security.  However, this stopped working when we moved to, I believe, Windows 2003 (before my time).

We've received a request to revive this functionality.  Is it possible to edit, or add/remove, users on Windows 2008 and newer servers from ColdFusion?  If not through a custom tag, can this be accomplished on the command line via `<cfExecute>`?

Answer (score 2):

CFX tags are compiled C++ tags. Here are the docs for CF 11, [Using CFX tags](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87506271).

I found the source code for `CFX_NT_USERDB` [here](http://web2.cnre.vt.edu/cfx/examples/nt_userdb/request.cpp), but I don't know if it's open source and I've no idea who created it.

Most likely, you might just need to recompile it using the updated C++ libraries on Windows 2003.

Other than that, you'd have to give the ColdFusion server user permission to create those accounts. But that would mean giving it more permissions than should be allowed for an application server.